# Functions with C linkage able to return class type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I observed a function in a dll which has C linkage. This function returns class type. I am not sure how this is made possible as C doesn't understand class.
  I wrote a sample dll and program myself and noted that the VC++ compiler shows a warning to this effect but doesn't stop you. The program is able to GetProcAddress of this function and call it to receive the returned object. The class definition was made available to program.
  Furthermore, if I write a function with C linkage that returns a class type where this class is not even exported, the compiler doesn't issue any warning. The program can consume this function from the dll provided the class definition is made available to it.
  Any thoughts on how this works? Is such a behavior compiler/platform specific?

Comment: With some tricks, that is how the inversion of control is implemented in c++. Do you have some links or examples?

Comment: Class signature would be useful. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: You know types don't exist at the binary level?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the behavior of `extern "C"`.

It only impacts the *name* of the function in the object file by preventing [name mangling](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FName_mangling&rct=j&q=name%20mangling&ei=V_M3TcO_Ac238gO3v4juCA&usg=AFQjCNHAo0_9oX8aBL1WAtRrC74Rf0jObg&cad=rja). It does not make a function neither "more C" or "less C++". The only additional limitation which `extern "C"` adds to a C++ function is that is shall not be overloaded.

Comment: True for MSVC++, not in general. There could be incompatible C and C++ ABI's, and an `extern "C"` function has to use the C ABI. Also, it's legal to overload an `extern "C"` function, as long as the other overloads aren't `extern "C"` themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you mentioned, extern "C" only impacts the name of the function. But during this name mangling, does the compiler care to check the types also in function signature. What happens if the return type is a class? e.g. extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Foo create_foo(); where Foo is a class.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible for functions with C linkage to return objects that can't be expressed in C so long as they can be manipulated in C.  According to my copy of *Design & Evolution of C++* (section 11.3.3):

> We considered several alternatives to the type-safe linkage schemes before deciding on the one actually added to the language [Stroustrup,1988]: ...
>
> - provide type-safe linkage only for functions that couldn't be C functions because they had types that couldn't be expressed in C. ...
>
> A function declared to have C linkage still has C++ calling semantics.  That is, the formal arguments must be declared, and the actual arguments must match under the C++ matching and ambiguity control rules. ...  Had we provided special services for C, we would have been obliged to add an unbounded set of language calling conventions to C++ compilers [for linking to Pascal, Fortran, PL/I, etc.]. ...
>
> Linkage, inter-language calls, and inter-language object passing are inherently difficult problems and have many implementation-dependent aspects. ... I expect we haven't heard the last of this matter.

That is, C++ linkage isn't based on whether the types involved are valid C types.  That is an intentional design decision.  It allows you to create a DLL compiled in C++ but that can be used from C via a header:

```
// in the header
struct Foo; // forward declaration

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct Foo* create_foo();

void destroy_foo(struct Foo*);

void foo_bar(struct Foo*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"

// now declare Foo
struct Foo {
    void bar();
};
#endif

// in the implementation file
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    Foo* create_foo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }

     void destroy_foo(Foo* f)
    {
        delete f;
    }

    void foo_bar(Foo* f)
    {
        f->bar();
    }
}

void Foo::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Foo::bar() called\n";
}
```

Note the calls to `new`, `delete` and `std::cout`.  These all require the C++ runtime.  Therefore, the implementation file must be compiled with C++, but since the functions have C linkage, the header can be used from either C or C++.

So how do you get a `Foo` in C?  In this case, you don't, because there's no way to fully declare it in the header in a way that C will understand.  Instead, C only sees the forward declaration, which creates an incomplete type.  C doesn't know how large an incomplete type is, so C functions can't create it or operate on them directly, but C does know how large a pointer to an incomplete type is, so C can operate on a pointer to an incomplete type.  You can get much more creative and actually create POD types in C++ that you can operate on directly in C.

As long as you only use `Foo*`s in C, you don't have to actually define the `Foo` struct in C.  It so happens that [APR uses a similar design](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/docs/APRDesign.html) ("Creating an APR Type," I couldn't find a better link).

Comment: Thank you.  I actually probably need to add a few `struct` keywords to the function signatures to keep C happy.  `Foo` in my example is in fact a POD, but I didn't want to cause unneeded confusion.  This kind of trick is common when writing plugins (XPCOM comes to mind).

Comment: Thanks a lot Max Lybbert. I appreciate your time and patience in writing such an elaborate reply. I agree with your point on C++ implementation and forward declaration / pointers. My case is 
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport) Foo create_foo(); 
The program that consumes this library is C++ program that does a GetProcAddress on create_foo.
but Foo is a class and not a struct. I expect extern "C" to do name mangling in a pure C way. C understands struct keyword but not a class and this is where my confusion lies. The compiler issues a warning also while compiling this create_foo..?

Comment: Although in my example I used a `struct` declaration, I believe it's legal to define something as a `struct` in C and the same thing as a `class` in C++ as long as you either (1) limit yourself to incomplete types in C or (2) make sure the `struct` and `class` are the same size.  Doing so can easily lead to confusion (the ability to access fields in the `struct` that aren't visible in the `class`), so it wouldn't surprise me if the compiler issued a warning.  Likewise, working with incomplete types can cause some confusion, so a compiler may choose to issue a warning there as well.

Answer (score 0):

A class object is basically just a struct object, with some extra "hidden" members for the vtbl and so on.

However, I'm not sure what you mean by "the program can consume this function provided the class definition is made available to it".  C would throw a compiler error on seeing `class Blah { ... };`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The program is written in C++ and the dll it consumes has a C interface. I have explained that above in reply to Max Lybbert.