# Input Mismatch JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

In working with JNA, I've had a very odd issue appear.
Here is my C++ code. -- Reduced for simplicity --

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" std::string func(int, int, int, double*, double*);

std::string func(int a, int b, int c, double* data1, double* data2) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return "Finished";
}
```

Here is the Java class:

```
class CLibOperator {
    interface CLib extends Library {
        CLib INSTANCE = 
            (CLib) Native.loadLibrary("libFile.so", CLib.class);

        String func(int a, int b, int c, double[] data1, double[] data2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] d1 = {10,20,30};
        double[] d2 = {111,222,333,444,555,666,777};
        CLib.INSTANCE.func(1, 2, 3, d1, d2);
    }
}
```

The output of the C function, however, is:

```
2
3
3856103913
```

What I expected is:

```
1
2
3
```

It seems like the first argument is being completely ignored. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't pass primitive arrays to JNA, so you'll have to allocate some Java side memory for those double arrays.    I have no idea if that has any relation to your symptoms though!

Comment: @DanielWiddis Wait, really? [I've used it successfully before](https://github.com/cxcorp/lacuna/blob/6028902c4e51dc8e42ceaca8e6e5a2cad90dda84/lacuna/lacuna-core/src/main/java/cx/corp/lacuna/core/windows/TokenOwnerNameFinder.java#L77).

Comment: @cubrr Gah.  I have avoided using that because of its temporary/scope nature but you're right, it  would work fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to return `std::string` from a function which has C-linkage specified (`extern "C"`). I'm surprised that your compiler doesn't complain to you about this. When returning structs or classes by value, it's common for a compiler (of course, depending on the compiler and the ABI it uses) to generate code which essentially equals to the struct being passed to the caller as a pointer passed to the function as a parameter.

Change the return type to `const char *`.

```
extern "C" const char *func(int, int, int, double *, double *);
```

You might also be interested in reading: [Functions with C linkage able to return class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744656/functions-with-c-linkage-able-to-return-class-type)